# Xspim simulator: transferring ints with mtc1

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

Code to transfer the integer 9 to the coprocessor, get the ceiling of its square root, then transfer this value back, and print it:

```
addi $t1, $zero, 9
mtc1 $t1, $f0
sqrt.s $f0, $f0      # (*)
ceil.w.s $f0, $f0   # (*)
mfc1 $t0, $f0
addi $v0, $zero, 1
addi $a0, $t0, 0
syscall
```

Note on lines with (*): (1) I also tried with .d instead of .s; (2) I also tried making the source and destination registers different (`$f0` to `$f2`, and back).

My result is 1 (if I take the floor instead, 0). However, if I comment the *-ed lines out, 9 is transferred to and fro fine: 9 is printed.

I added a syscall "print_double" (=3) after transfer (and before transfer back to CPU) to print the number transferred, and a very small positive number is printed.

My questions:

(a) What is going on?

(b) `mtc1`: is the integer transferred from the CPU received as a double, or a single? Before sending it back with `mfc1`, does it need to be a single or double, or does it not matter? (I experimented using `cvt.d.s`, etc., to no avail)

Remark: I'm doing this for fun using "Computer Organization and Design" (Patterson, Hennessy). The 4th edition has the syntax for `mtc1` wrong in appendix B.10 - order of `rd` and `rs` should be as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `cvt.s.w` to convert the loaded integer to single-precision floating point fixes the problem:

```
addi $t1, $zero, 36
mtc1 $t1, $f0
cvt.s.w $f0,$f0    # convert the integer in $f0 to floating point
sqrt.s $f0, $f0      
ceil.w.s $f0, $f0  # ceil and convert from floating point to integer 
mfc1 $t0, $f0
addi $v0, $zero, 1
addi $a0, $t0, 0
syscall
```

Comment: Thank you! Works for me too now. This obviously also answers (b) after transfer, it needs to first be made a double (cvt.d.w) or single (cvt.s.w) precision float.